# Biqquery SQL parse JSON array and count by element type

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

Biqgquery SQL experts, I need some help with parsing a JSON from. table. One of the columns has a Json payload

`{"bboxes":[[0.371046781539917,0.5638647079467773,0.36434206366539,0.970723032951355],[0.5918399691581726,0.7923348546028137,0.33475741744041443,0.9601762294769287],[0.4485582411289215,0.674128532409668,0.34045588970184326,0.9819985628128052],[0.6591917276382446,0.7791954278945923,0.3623618483543396,0.7641286849975586],[0.5235867500305176,0.6976093649864197,0.28036248683929443,0.5006953477859497],[0.6841945052146912,0.9479447603225708,0.34488487243652344,0.9769046306610107],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],"confidences":[0.15634897,0.14026128,0.12496623,0.087290496,0.05375478,0.050469983,0,0,0,0],"displayNames":["employee","employee","employee","employee","closed_register","employee","employee","employee","employee","employee"],"ids":["4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432","8799389907823886336","4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432","4187703889396498432"]}`

I have to get a count of the displaynames by type. E.g. Employee count, Guest count, Closed_Register count.

How do I do this?

I have user the JSON_QUERY to parse the displaynames

SELECT

JSON_QUERY(annotation,"$.displayNames") as detects
FROM
tableA

But that returns a json which prints like a list. How do I take each of the rows and run a count on the items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select type, count(*) type_count
from your_table, unnest(json_extract_array(annotation,"$.displayNames")) as type
group by type
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]